# my api call doesnot work in javascript but works fine with in postman and browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, web

this the html file

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>"api call"</title>

    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="demo">

                <script>
                    function list() {
                        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhttp.open("GET","192.168.0.101:8000/students/",true);
                        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token ad4140b1caa4f98160bdc979a71a7215ae5972fe");
                        xhttp.send();
                        var1 response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                        document.write(var1);
                    }

                </script>

                <button type="button" onclick="list()">click to get the list</button>

            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

when i run this in my browser request is not sent(i cannot see anything in my traceball in backend)
the url works fine if used in the browser and postman
[this is the screenshot of postman request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiJX6.png)

the backend is in django

this is the error i get in console

```
var1 response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
```

error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: What error do you receive ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai i have edited, u can see at the end

Comment: Have a look to my anwer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai i get this error now in the console                                  Uncaught ReferenceError: list is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (javascriptapi:21)

Comment: Maybe you make some changes. This error looks like does not find your function for click event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is with the `xhttp.open` code. When you ask to perform the "GET," setting the boolean at the end to true will mean the request will perform asynchronously. You should set this variable to `false`, which means the method does not return until the response is received.

Try changing

```
xhttp.open("GET","192.168.0.101:8000/students/",true);
```

to:

```
xhttp.open("GET","192.168.0.101:8000/students/",false);
```

Here are good sources:

- [XMLHttpRequest.open() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open)
- [How to call a REST web service API from Javascript button Handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975619/how-to-call-a-rest-web-service-api-from-javascript-button-handler)

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Since it seems you are the owner of the server, you can try manually implementing a CORS header on your server, or use [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms) (which bypasses CORS). Here's [some info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on CORS and implementing on MDN. There also this [nice source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309824/calling-external-api-with-javascript) on SO. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, that's a good point, but it is not recommended to use `async:false` for ajax(it's a bad practice) because can freezes the window.

Comment: That's good to keep in mind! If Kethan wants to implement an [ajax promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751395/whats-the-difference-between-promise-and-ajax) that would allow him to keep the request asynchronous, right?

Comment: @KethanChauhan Is your authorization supposed to resemble: `"Token ad4140b1caa4f98160bdc979a71a7215ae5972fe"`? That format seems a little off. Are you receiving errors in the console?

Comment: @cosinepenguin yes i get an error in the console,see up there i have edited

Comment: @cosinepenguin see the screenshot that i have added

Answer (score 1):

When you make the `request` the content of response will be parsed automatically.

Change

```
var1 response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
```

To

```
var1 response = xhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: list is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (javascriptapi:21)   
@Alexandru-IonutMihail i get this error now